# C# copying creation time of file in cd

Tags: c#, copy, cd

I'm trying to copy file from cd and after copy it to copy also the creation date of the file.
The copy command looks like this:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyFile(sourcePath, destPath);
```

It works properly and copies the file from the cd (source) to the desktop (destination).

The next step I do is to take the creation time from the source file:

```
DateTime creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(sourcePath);
```

This step is also works properly and the creation time is in the creationTime variable.

The last step is to put the creation time in the destination file:

```
File.SetCreationTime(destPath, creationTime);
```

And here is the problem, the last step throws "Access is denied: "C:...." (destination path)".

The wierd thing is that I have access to the file in the cd (source) but why can't I change the creation time of the file in the destination?
Secondly, When I'm trying to make the exact same copy from disk on key to the desktop or from one folder in the computer to another, it works perfect.
That made me think that the problem is when I'm trying to copy from cd, I checked that on another cd and same result happen, it could not copy the creation date.
How can I solve it and copy the creation time?

Comment: Change your system clock to the creation date from the CD and then copy the file. heheh ;)

Comment: I was just joking.. But i want to help. Do you have sufficient rights to edit the file where it's located on the desktop?

Comment: Instead of copying the file with CopyFile, open the file from the CD with File.OpenRead(), create the destination file with File.Create(), and copy the bytes of the source file using Stream.CopyTo(). When finished you can do whatever on the destination file I think.

Comment: Why are you using Visual Basic to copy the file ?

Comment: Yes I have rights to edit file where its located in the desktop, the creation tome copy works properly if I copy from other source (not cd) to the same folder in the desktop @NickGames

Comment: I dont want to copy the bytes because its not working with big size files and anyway I have rights to edit the file in the deaktop. And Im using visual basic because it copies much more faster @Oguz Ozgul

Comment: I don't believe that Visual Basic copies faster. Is it slower if you use System.IO.File.Copy()? May be the case is, it starts the copying in the background and returns so you think it is fast, and you try to access the file while the copying has not finished yet.

Comment: Okay ill try to use mutex, and to copy with File.Copy.

Comment: Why the mutex? File.Copy is synchronous.

Comment: By the way, "I dont want to copy the bytes because its not working with big size files" is not true, when you do File.Copy it copies bytes. (It has to copy the bytes. This is not a MOVE operation, a new file is created, thus, all the bytes have to be copied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
For the next who'll have the same problem, the problem was that the files that on the cd are read-only files, after you copy a file it still a read-only file.
In order to set it's creation date you have to remove the read-only attribute from the new file you copied and just then to do the set of the creation date.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're getting "Access Denied" with `File.SetCreationTime`. What happens if you right click and run Visual Studio as Administrator? This would also elevate your program and may prove that it's access rights.

Anyway, another way you can change the created/modified date is using [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void ChangeCreationTime(string filePath, DateTime creationDate)
{
    var result = new FileInfo(filePath) {CreationTime = creationDate};
}
```

You can also change the modified date with `{LastWriteTime = dateTime}`. See below:

[image]

Unfortunately I don't have a CD right here to test this directly, so apologies if you end up at square one again.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried this and I found out that the problem wasn't in the creation changing, it was because of the file attribute, you can see my answer

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Now we can both feel stupid for not looking at something so basic ;-)